# What is the best way to point to common dependency from JS modules bundled together?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, hugo, esbuild

*(Code below is a simple example, real scenario is bigger)*

I have two modules, `mod1.js` and `mod2.js`, which are bundled together (using [esbuild](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild)). They share a common dependency, `util.js`.

Problem is: when code in `mod2.js` imports `util.js` (using same alias), there's a conflict with names.

`util.js`:

```js
export class Util {
  ...
}
```

`mod1.js`:

```js
import Util from "./util.js";
...
```

`mod2.js`:

```js
/* this raises an error of variable already declared */
import Util from "./util.js";
...
```

If I change alias in `mod2.js`, error goes away, as expected. But changing aliases every time I import `util.js` is a bit clumsy, and makes me think there has to be another way.

**Is there a better approach to point to a common dependency from multiple modules which are bundled together?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not a problem with your code, rather with the `esbuild` tool. How are you using it, what output format did you choose? Also it's feature list mentions "*Scope hoisting for ES6 modules*", which might cause this.

Comment: Yes, the docs for [ES6 linking](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/blob/master/docs/architecture.md#es6-linking) and [scope hoisting](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/blob/master/docs/architecture.md#scope-hoisting) confirm my hunch. How exactly are you "bundling" your two modules *mod1.js* and *mod2.js* "together"? What single entrypoint do you use? Have you taken a look at [code splitting](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/blob/master/docs/architecture.md#code-splitting)?

Comment: Thanks, @Bergi! In fact, I'm using `esbuild` through [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/hugo-pipes/js/). The script files are [concatenated](https://gohugo.io/hugo-pipes/bundling/#readout) *before* passing them to `esbuild`. I realize now that I'm bypassing `esbuild` bundling by making this step with Hugo... And the format I use for `esbuild` is `iife`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With help from @Bergi's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63181250/what-is-the-best-way-to-point-to-common-dependency-from-js-modules-bundled-toget#comment111730735_63181250), I figured out that I was not using `esbuild` to bundle my files, but rather using [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/hugo-pipes/js/) to [concatenate](https://gohugo.io/hugo-pipes/bundling/#readout) them, and passing this to `esbuild`.

This leads to mentioned error because there are multiple `import`s **in the same file**, which `esbuild` correctly doesn't recognize as valid. Instead, [using `esbuild` to bundle my files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63094323/10321889) gives me correct results.

I'm still using Hugo, but I have a single entry point which it consumes, that `import`s all my scripts. From example, I have another file, say `master.js`:

`master.js`:

```js
import mod1 from "./mod1.js";
import mod2 from "./mod2.js";
```

And I then pass this `master.js` to Hugo, using its `js.Build` function, which internally uses `esbuild`. This way I can import `util.js` using same alias, because these `import`s are in separate files, using [ES6 linking from `esbuild`](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/blob/master/docs/architecture.md#es6-linking).